# Mounting directory in Neo4j Docker container is resulting in empty directory on MacOS

Tags: docker, docker-compose, neo4j

I've been trying to figure out how to mount data into the neo4j import directory on MacOS. Here is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
services:
  neo4j:
    image: docker.io/neo4j:4.3.2
    container_name: neo4j
    ports:
      - 7474:7474
      - 7687:7687
    volumes:
      - $HOME/neo4j/logs:/logs
      - $HOME/neo4j/dummydata:/import
```

As you can see I am trying to mount the dummydata directory, which contains some csv files into the import directory of the neo4j docker container. But when I take a look at the container by running `docker exec -ti neo4j` I can see that the import directory is totally empty in the container. I did the same thing for another docker container based on the python:3.8-slim image. Here the csv files were mounted into the container. So that's why in the end it must come done to some neo4j specific stuff that I don't get. Does somebody know what I've been doing wrong?

It's interesting though that the neo4j container was able to write a log file into the logs directory on my local machine. So he is definitely working with the mounted directories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

is the `/import` the right folder?

did you try using?

```yaml
services:
  neo4j:
    image: docker.io/neo4j:4.3.2
    container_name: neo4j
    ports:
      - 7474:7474
      - 7687:7687
    volumes:
      - $HOME/neo4j/logs:/logs
      - $HOME/neo4j/dummydata:/var/lib/neo4j/import #changed folder
```

source [here](https://neo4j.com/developer/docker-run-neo4j/)

Comment: Interesting that they specify the other directories without the prefix. I don't understand the difference here.